# Preventing cheat in a clicker game in web

Tags: javascript, html, anti-cheat

If you seen my previous question, you will know that I'm starting on a project. It requires you to grind clicks then spend it. But I want to prevent user from cheating using auto-clicker extensions. So, is there anyways that I can prevent user from cheating?

Here's my code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

body{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #11998e, #38ef7d)
}

#title{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
    user-select: none;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

#button{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    user-select: none;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
}

#button:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    background-color: white;
}

#button:active{
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is just test</title>
        <script src="clicker.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="clicker.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="title">Clicker Test</p>
        <div id="button">
            <span id="text">Score:</span>
            <span id="score">0</span>
        </div>
        <script>
            let counter = 0;
  
            document.getElementById('button').onclick = () => {
                document.getElementById('button').style.width = '45%';
                document.getElementById('button').style.width = '50%'
                counter = counter + 1;
                document.getElementById('score').innerText = counter;
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fundamentally, not possible. The code runs on the client, which means that the client can patch/modify the code and functionality as they want.

Comment: I mean, that's what the "[NoCAPTCHA reCAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA#No_CAPTCHA_reCAPTCHA_(v2+))" does; it's effectively a single-click clicker which distinguishes between bots and humans, ostensibly based on things like mouse movements before the click. So it's somewhat possible, but definitely not simple.

Comment: So I guess the question is "what are you trying to achieve" and "can you achieve it in some other way"...

Comment: As @CertainPerformance said, a user could change your code in browser and my idea could work only if the user don't know about developer tools. 
One of the possible solution, it's disable the button for a short period of time (e.g. 60ms) after each click. In this case, click between 0-60ms will be ignored by your code.

Comment: For a very contrasting approach, see for instance Wordle, which makes no attempt at preventing or even obfuscating anything, not even the list of solutions